# generating .notification.localstore.json for Micorosft ConversationBot

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-teams

I need to use a ConversationBot to send messages to MS Teams users. I got the code below from TeamsToolkit generated example app. It works, but it uses user ids stored in `.notification.localstore.json` generated i presume at some point during TeamsToolkit setup.

```js
import { ConversationBot } from '@microsoft/teamsfx'

// Create bot.
export const bot = new ConversationBot({
    // The bot id and password to create BotFrameworkAdapter.
    // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about adapters.
    adapterConfig: {
        appId: '...',
        appPassword: '...',
    },
    // Enable notification
    notification: {
        enabled: true,
        /// storage: ...
    },
})

let me = await bot.notification
    .findMember(async (member) => member.account.aadObjectId == "myAad")

me.sendMessage("test")
```

The readme provided in the example says

> Note: It's recommended to use your own shared storage for production environment

Which is exactly what I'm trying to do, except I can't find any documentation on what exaclty are the methods supposed to return, and where do I get all the conversation ids required.

Comment: Could you please share the sample link which you are referring?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/blob/f4116d5bf67620a8a734d3acc0fc2213de21c2a2/templates/bot/js/notification-restify/README.md

Comment: Could you please refer below sample for bot conversation: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file isn't generated during setup, but rather is written to as different events are sent from Teams to your bot

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/main/msteams-platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams.md#notification-based-on-events

> Bot Framework SDK provides the functionality to proactively message in
> Teams. TeamsFx SDK provides the functionality to manage bot's
> conversation references when a bot event is triggered. TeamsFx SDK
> recognizes the following bot events:
>
> Event Behavior The first time you install a bot to a person, group, or
> Team. Add the target conversation reference to the storage. When the
> bot is uninstalled from a person, group, or Team. Remove the target
> conversation reference from the storage. When the team installed by
> bot is deleted.   Remove the target conversation reference from the
> storage. When the team installed by bot is restored.  Add the target
> conversation reference to the storage. When the bot sends
> messages. When the target conversation reference doesn't exist, add it
> to the storage.